# "Permission denied" error while using VisibleOnScreen property on an web element in test complete tool

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I am unable to use "VisibleOnScreen" property on an Web element in test complete tool.Error is inconsistent, sometimes it works fine.
Error:Permission denied
      Error location:

Eg:-

```
        var obj = Sys.Browser("*").Page("*").FindChildByXPath(xpath);
        if(obj!=null) {
         if(obj.VisibleOnScreen) {
           Log.Message("Object is visible on Screen");
         }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the object returned by the FindChildByXPath method on existence? Check obj.Exists before checking the VisibleOnScreen property.

Comment: If the object is not found, FindChildByXPath method returns null, so we cannot use obj.Exists because it leads to runtime error. I am using "if(obj != null) { }" condition to verify the existence of the object before checking the VisibleOnScreen property.